# When a file is uploaded from php uploader WinSCP is unable to modify it

Tags: php, file-upload, phpbb, phpbb3, winscp

If a file is uploaded or created in any way by a php file I cannot modify it, however I can delete it. This is really irritating.

P.S.: All of the files that have been created or uploaded have been done with phpBB 3.0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, PHP is running under the web server user (httpd, www, www-data or similar). When files are uploaded, they are owned by this user.

You cannot modify the files as you are not the owner. You can however delete them as you most probably own the upload directory.

Some solutions are:

- check your phpBB FTP settings
- run PHP via [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) or [mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) which would allow you to define the user running PHP
- set the file permissions to group or world writable if you really must edit them outside of PHP (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: The easiest way to fix it is to add the web server group (www-data in my case) to my user and make sure it's group-writable.